app scripts permissions forced me to use "tester" mode
I used to run my spreadsheets script with no problem. first run setup - allowed permissions, as I used URLFetchApp. everything worked fine.
one day, "the app is blocked" came up and I was advised to connect to GCP project. now, it works, but I have to authorize again every 7 days, even though Im the owner. how can I revert back to working without GCP and permanent authorization? I know it's possible as my friend is using the same script and has no issues.
cheers
I tried a few user types. set myself up as a user, owner, editor, etc. I tried using a new file. every script that has the URLFETCHAPP will fail. I tried adding scopes to the json. I tried adding the pragma statement which helped for SpreadsheetApp but not for URLFETCH.
Ive also tried:
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

and also tried oath scopes.
nothing worked.
